# i just want to print the first value(name) from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the below code I am trying to print out just the first value (name) of the array, but it doesn't work as I expect:

```
function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}// Our Person constructor


// Now we can make an array of people
var family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy", 6);
// loop through our new array
for(i = 0; i <= family.Length; i++) {
  console.log( family[i].this.name); 
}
```

Comment: `Length` should not be capitalised.

Comment: The loop should be while `i < family.length`, not `<=`.

Comment: You should use `family.push(...)` to add elements to the array instead of manually keeping track of the index.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the "this" keyword incorrectly. When you access family[i] you are already accessing an instance of that prototype in JavaScript. Just drop the "this."

Answer (score 0):

To get the first item from the array you could do the below without the loop:

```
console.log(family[0].name);
```

Without looping, as the loop is unnecessary if you know which item you want to print.

Or, if the loop is necessary you could add some logic such as

```
if(i === 0) {
  console.log(family[0].name);
}
```

You do not need to use `this` when accessing the `name` property of the object in the array.

Answer (score -1):

```
function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}// Our Person constructor


// Now we can make an array of people
var family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy", 6);

// loop through our new array
for(i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {
  console.log( family[i].name); 
}
```